# Android sms is always sent same contact

Tags: android, android-asynctask, sms

I am trying to send sms to multiple contacts using asynctask. But when i click send button sms is sent to only one number which is top of the my selected contact list. And number of the sent sms is equal to size of the selected contact list. I wrote my sms send  code below.  How can i fix this problem?

```
  @Override
  protected final String doInBackground(List<kisiler>... lists) {
      int progress=0;
      final List<contacts> k=lists[0];
      dialog.setMax(k.size());

      while (progress<dialog.getMax()){

            try{

                final String m=k.get(k.size()-1).getName();


                SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

                publishProgress(String.valueOf(k.size()-1),String.valueOf(k.size()),m,String.valueOf(dialog.getMax()));
                PendingIntent sendPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);


                getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                    @Override
                    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                        switch (getResultCode()) {
                            case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                          Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.sent_to_sms)+contact.getName(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                break;

                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.failure+kisi2.getIsim(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_service, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                                break;
                            case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }, new IntentFilter(SENT+m));

                smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact.getNumber(), null, location_information(location), sendPI, null);


            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

          progress++;

      }

      return "Done";
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You're always refering to the same `contact` variable.
 You need to change it with `k` list and `progress` number like this:

```
k.get(progress) // your current contact
```

Change it to something like this:

```
  @Override
  protected final String doInBackground(List<kisiler>... lists) {
      int progress=0;
      final List<contacts> k=lists[0];
      dialog.setMax(k.size());

  while (progress<dialog.getMax()){

        try{

            final String m=k.get(k.size()-1).getName();


            SmsManager smsManager = SmsManager.getDefault();

            publishProgress(String.valueOf(k.size()-1),String.valueOf(k.size()),m,String.valueOf(dialog.getMax()));
            PendingIntent sendPI = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getActivity(), 0, new Intent(), 0);


            getActivity().registerReceiver(new BroadcastReceiver() {
                @Override
                public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
                    switch (getResultCode()) {
                        case Activity.RESULT_OK:
                      Toast.makeText(getActivity(),getString(R.string.sent_to_sms)+k.get(progress),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            break;

                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_GENERIC_FAILURE:
                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.failure+kisi2.getIsim(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NO_SERVICE:

                            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), R.string.no_service, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_NULL_PDU:
                            break;
                        case SmsManager.RESULT_ERROR_RADIO_OFF:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            }, new IntentFilter(SENT+m));

            smsManager.sendTextMessage(k.get(progress).getNumber(), null, location_information(location), sendPI, null);


        }catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

      progress++;

  }
```

Comment: Thank you i sloved the problem. But there is no problem here: k.get(k.size()-1).

I will change this line:
                smsManager.sendTextMessage(contact.getNumber(), null, location_information(location), sendPI, null);

to:

   smsManager.sendTextMessage(k.get(k.size()-1).getNumber(), null, konum_bilgi(location), sendPI, null);

It works

Comment: If you change it to k.get(k.size()-1) it will always return the last element of the array, take care

Comment: I am creating dynamic linear layout and add the contact inside it. Dynamic layout first element contains list's last element. Thats why i wrote it)